# Need to make a dataframe that tallies the number of file types in each folder

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe that shows the count of specific file types in each subdirectory. This is the code I currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib as pl
import os

Current_File_Types = ['fort.13', 'fort.15', 'fort.26', 'fort.61', 'HsatMaxele.63', 'maxele.63', 'maxele400sec.63', 'maxele400sec_index.63', 'maxrs.63', 'maxvel.63', 'maxwvel.63', 'minpr.63', 'swan_DIR_max.63', 'swan_HS_max.63', 'swan_TM01_max.63', 'swan_TPS_max.63', 'Tm01atMaxele.63', 'TpsatMaxele.63', 'fort.63.gz', 'fort.64.gz', 'fort.73.gz', 'fort.74.gz', 'rads.64.gz', 'swan_DIR.63.gz', 'swan_HS.63.gz', 'swan_TM01.63.gz', 'swan_TPS.63.gz']
p = r'P:\02\NJ_NYC_Coastal_Surge\STUDY_COASTAL_TO01\TECHNICAL\ENG_FLOOD_HAZ_DEV\COASTAL\SURGE\Production\ARCHIVE\RegionII_NYNJSurge\Production'
datafiles = pl.Path(p).rglob('*')
datafiles = list(datafiles)
len(datafiles)
extenstions = list(set([d.suffix for d in datafiles]))
adcirc_files = []
for i in extenstions:
    try:
        extnumber = int(i[1:])
        adcirc_files.append(extnumber)
    except:
        continue
adcirc_files_by_type = {}
for ftype in adcirc_files:
    adcirc_files_by_type[ftype] = sorted([f for f in datafiles if f.suffix == f'.{ftype}'])
f1 = 63
f63_types = set([f.name for f in adcirc_files_by_type[f1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=sorted(f63_types) + Current_File_Types)
index_list = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(p):
    path_name = os.path.basename(dirpath)
    index_list.append(path_name)
removed_duplicates_index_list = list(dict.fromkeys(index_list))
df = df.assign(Production_ID = removed_duplicates_index_list)
df = df.set_index('Production_ID')
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df
```

So for each row in the dataframe, I would like to place a 0 where there is no specific file type in the folder and a 1 if there is a file type in that folder. For example, if in the first folder there are "fort.13" and "fort.15" files only in the folder, then a 1 should be placed in the columns titled "fort.13" and "fort.15" while the other columns should have a 0.

This is the current sample output of the code:

```
                       'HsatMaxele.63'   'Tm01atMaxele.63'      'TpsatMaxele.63'
Production_ID
ADCIRC_SWAN_FORT13      NaN               NaN                    NaN
ADCIRC_SWAN_FORT14      NaN               NaN                    NaN
...
tide98                  NaN               NaN                    NaN
tide99                  NaN               NaN                    NaN
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show your sample output in a tabular manner?

Comment: @Datanovice please see above.

Comment: @Datanovice did you have a chance to take a look at this?

Comment: looking now, `Production ID` and the Column names don't make much sense to me, I know how I would answer your initial question, which is to count files by ext within a given directory (and sub-directory) if needed.

Comment: @Datanovice I would be glad if you are able to show me how to count files by ext within a given directory (and sub-directory).

Comment: posted an answer, hopefully that pushes you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

This is how I would handle this task relying on pathlib :

```
file_dirs = [f for f in Path.cwd().rglob('*.')] # replace .cwd() with Path(your_dir)...
```

then create a dict to hold the parent folder as the key, and the ext as the values.

```
file_dict = {}
for x in file_dirs:
    file_dict[f'{x.parent}'] = file_dict.get(f'{x.parent}', []) + [x.suffix]
```

then just pass this to a dataframe

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_dict, orient="index", columns=["Ext"]).rename_axis(
    "Parent"
).reset_index()
```

you can then just do a grouby on the parent folder to get a count of Extensions

```
df.groupby(['Parent','Ext'])['Ext'].count()
```